# default value of JAVA_HOME seems to be overwriting the value set by: /etc/profile.d/java.sh

Tags: java, linux

I've created a file `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` that includes (among other things) the line of code: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30`. However, when I log in via SSH or reboot the linux Centos 6.2 server, I always see:

```
[root@host3 /etc/profile.d]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk
```

This is a new installation and server, so there's not much else done. It seems that the java.sh file is executing upon reboot or SSH login, however, the value of JAVA_HOME is being overwritten by the default value of `/usr/local/jdk` somehow. There isn't even a directory `jdk` under `/usr/local`.

Any idea how to correct this? The value of JAVA_HOME needs to be set (as done in java.sh) for all users.

UPDATE 1:

I checked the /etc/profile file and searched for the text `jdk` as well as `JAVA` and neither were found. I also checked the /root/.bash_profile and it shows as follows:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Also, if I source java.sh, everything gets set correctly. But if I reboot server, JAVA_HOME goes back to `/usr/local/jdk`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am really struggling with this as there is indicator of any issue anywhere.

Comment: Just found the culprit. see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the /etc/profile file or the .bash_profile/.profile in your home directory.

Comment: If all you want to do is set the correct JAVA_HOME, add that command to your .bash_profile. If you want to dig further, first find out what your shell is. Assuming its bash, check the contents of /etc/profile and take it from there. In my /etc/profile, it sources every file under /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; so take a look at the *.sh files under /etc/profile.d. Also check /etc/bashrc and your local .bashrc

Answer (score 2):

It appears that cPanel adds the following lines to the `/etc/bashrc` file to set the JAVA_HOME to it's default.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip
```

So, if you have cPanel installed, make sure you check this file as well.

Comment: Was breaking my head since morning. cPanel was troubling me till i saw your post. Thanks @Sina